# Mongo: Add partial unique index on array of key-value pairs

Tags: mongodb

In a collection, I have a metadata field thats just an array of key-value data for generic data.

```
[
  { key: "test1": value: "value1" },
  { key: "test2": value: "value2" },
  { key: "test3": value: "value3" },
]
```

Isit possible to add a partial unique index such that I can only one record with `key=someId, value=someId`. If not, what might be a good way to index such field for more performant search by key value pairs (or do u recommend a different approach). For example:

```
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "metadata": [
    { key: "oid": value: "value1" }
  ]
},
// This record is valid
{ 
  "name": "abc",
  "metadata": [
    { key: "oid": value: "value2" }
  ]
},
// This record is invalid since value1 is duplicated
{    
  "name": "123",
  "metadata": [
    { key: "oid": value: "value1" } 
  ]
}
```

---

UPDATE:

Following @KaushikDas answer, I made an index like suggested

```
db.collection.metadata.createIndex(
   { metadata: 1 },
   { unique: true,
     partialFilterExpression: { 'metadata.key': 'myid' }
   }
)
```

It does prevent me from adding duplicate key values, however, when I try to do a query like

```
db.getCollection('collname').find({
    "metadata" : { $elemMatch: { key: 'myid', value: 'myvalue' } }
}).explain()
```

It doesnt use the index why is that?

Comment: Seems like that should work with a unique compound index on key and value, have you tried that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this.

### For Uniqueness

[partialFilterExpression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/)

```
db.collection.metadata.createIndex(
   { metadata: 1 },
   { unique: true, // makes it unique
       partialFilterExpression: { "metadata.key": { $exists: true } }  // index only if metadata is not empty array
   }
)
```

---

**Assumptions**

- `metadata` will always have `key`

---

**Valid**

Will allow multiple empty arrays

```
metadata:[] // record 1 not indexed
metadata:[] // record 2 not indexed

{ "name": "abc", "metadata": [ { key: "oid": value: "value2" } ] } // will be indexed
{ "name": "abc", "metadata": [ { key: "oid": value: "value2" } ] } // will be indexed
```

---

**Invalid**

```
{ "name": "abc", "metadata": [ { key: "oid": value: "value3" } ] } // will be indexed
{ "name": "abc", "metadata": [ { key: "oid": value: "value3" } ] } // not unique is invalid record
```

---

### For Query to use index

> create a compound index on key and value

```
db.getCollection.metadata.createIndex({ "metadata.key": 1, "metadata.value": 1 });
```

Comment: Yep, but any possibility to index key-value combinations and maybe even ensure they pair is unique?

Comment: @JiewMeng Yes, it will ensure the uniqueness of the key-value pair. you can test it out  it should work fine :)

Comment: Thank you, I updated my post. I notice that while it prevents me from adding duplicate key/value pair, it doesnt get used in queries

Comment: Also, I did `partialFilterExpression: { 'metadata.key': 'myid' }` which I expected it to only index when key is "myid", however, it prevents me from writing data that might be duplicate. Any way around this? Eg. I may want to store `{ "categoy": "xxx" }` and its ok for this to be duplicated

Comment: @JiewMeng updated answer, now you can use another index for your queries.

Comment: I think I see the issue with the unique index now ... as long as it matches the partial filter expression, it ensures all items in the array are unique ... is there no way to just ensure those items with the match are unique?

Answer (score 1):

Moreover, when you are going to read this collection, please make sure your query predicate should be contain the condition of '**partialFilterExpression**', otherwise it will scan whole collection (Index will not honor) and degraded the performance while reading huge data.

**Other Views** : If you want to alter the schema and want to explore other ways then you have to tell us use case and access pattern of this collection, based on that we do recommend correct data model. Your meta data key value pair is called '**attribute pattern**' and this is very useful for eCommerce.

Comment: You are right ... I realized now while the unique index prevents me from writing duplicate data, it doesnt use the index for queries ... can you elaborate on "make sure your query predicate should be contain the condition of 'partialFilterExpression'". I tried to query `"metadata" : { $elemMatch: { key: 'mykey', value: 'myvalue' } }`

Comment: You can explain this find({ "metadata.key": { $exists: true }) , it will honor index, because partial filter and the query condition is matching. Indexes are following B-trees algo, when ever you do partial index, actually we assume you want to reduce index overhead. In your scenario partial index will not help, because each and every docs are not index thats why partially indexed, so your query should pick ony those patial records, those it already indexed. Suggested a multikey unique index.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/#unique-multikey-index